# Declare a variable using 'var' in a with{ } statement

Tags: javascript, with-statement

I am just studying You-dont-know-js book on github, currently scope-closure, chapter2 : https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/scope-closures/ch2.md

I encountered a problem that I am not clear: declare a variable using 'var' in a with{ } statement. 
Here's the explanation regarding this:

> Note: Even though a with block treats an object like a lexical scope,
>   a normal **var declaration** inside that with block will not be scoped
>   to that with block, but instead the containing function scope.

According to this explanation, I changed a little bit the code provided in this chapter:

```js
function foo(obj) {
 with (obj) {
  var a = 2;  //Here I added "var" declaration 
 }
  console.log('foo, '+ a)  //Here I added console function to see if a is in foo scope
}

var o1 = {
 a: 3
};

var o2 = {
 b: 3
};

foo( o1 );   // foo, undefined
console.log( o1.a );     //2

foo( o2 );   // foo, 2
console.log( o2.a );    //undefined
```

for foo(o2),  my understand is that because o2 has no property named 'a', the var declaration inside the with block just created a variable a within foo function scope, and the result makes sense.
but for foo(o1), the var declaration just changed o1.a to value 2, but why console.log('foo, '+a)shows 'foo, undefined'? As I understand, the result should either be 'foo, 2' or reference error: a is not defined.

Could anyone explain this issue? thanks.

Comment: The most important thing to take away from that lesson is how `with` is deprecated and shouldn't be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the compiler does:

```
function foo(obj) {
    var a;                   // hoisted
    with (obj) {
        a = 2;               // take a from object if exists, otherwise take variable
    }
    console.log('foo, '+ a);
}
```

The first case creates an `a` variable in scope of the function, then the `var` statement is removed/hoisted and only the assignment part remains.

And while `obj` contains a property `a`, the value is assigned to the object's property with the `with` statement.

The local `a` did not recieved any value.

In the second call, there is no property of `a` and therefore the variable `a` gets a value.

Comment: so the description "Note: Even though a with block treats an object like a lexical scope, a normal var declaration inside that with block will not be scoped to that with block, but instead the containing function scope." actually did what you described, correct?